# Assign next n iterations to tuple

Tags: python

Is there more sophisticated way of doing this?

```
node = next(iterable), next(iterable), next(iterable)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice` to select items from an iterable. Note that iterators are iterable, but not every iterable is an iterator with a `next` (or `__next__` in Python3) method.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> iterator = (x for x in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
>>> tuple(islice(iterator, 3))
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Alternatively, a simple comprehension:

```
>>> iterator = (x for x in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
>>> tuple(next(iterator) for _ in range(3))
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

The name `_` has no special meaning for the interpreter (outside of interactive sessions, where it stores the result of the last executed statement) but is noticed as the name for a throwaway-variable by Python programmers.